# Windows waitfor.exe signaling protocol needed

Tags: windows, networking, batch, powershell, documentation

Windows has a **waitFor.exe** command available for use in in batch and powershell (and any other language that can call an executable), which allows you to sends or waits for a signal on a system, thereby allow execution synchronization across a network - although it also works fine on a single computer.

It's very useable, but due to lack of good documentation it's mostly abused to insert a pause in batch files using it's timeout option.

The only documentation I can find is this:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731613(v=ws.11).aspx, which provides a very basic usage usage for the specific **waitFor.exe** command in Windows - but offers nothing about how it's actually implemented nor how I ensure that it will work (== isn't blocked by some firewall) in a given network.

I'd like to be able to embed sending and receiving these signals in my own code, but can't find anything on how to do so - not even the most basic protocol and packet format seems available.

My questions,

1. What network protocol is used for this? (As @Seth mentioned, it's probably RPC - but then, how is it implemented?)
2. What is the packet format used?
3. What network ports are required to route these signals?

In other words, I need to know everything needed to implement this in my own programs.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: As by the examples the signal seems to be a simple string you can probably send any string. Usually Windows relies on RPC calls for such functions.

Comment: Just found @eryksun [2014 SO comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675500): waitfor.exe is based on [mailslots](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365576). `waitfor someevent` creates a mailslot named `\\.\mailslot\WAITFOR.EXE\someevent`. Sending the signal via `waitfor /si someevent` opens a handle for `\\*\mailslot\WAITFOR.EXE\someevent`, where "*" has the UNC provider broadcast the message to every computer on the domain. `waitfor /s %COMPUTERNAME% /si someevent` specifically `opens \\[computer_name]\mailslot\WAITFOR.EXE\someevent` instead of broadcasting the signal.